# Updating Cart content based on option selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

While implementing a Cart, I want to allow the user to change the quantity of an item that he has in his Cart. Right now, I have a select tag to display quantity, with the correct quantity pre-selected. What I want to do is this: as soon as the user selects another option in the select tag, the quantity in Cart is updated. How should I proceed? Right now the quantity is displayed as follows:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <%= select_tag "quantity", options_for_select((1..item.quantity).to_a, quantity) %>
<% end %>
```

One more thing. My show_cart is a partial that doesn't include the checkout button, if that's of any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can achieve through AJAX. You need to execute jQuery whenever the user selects a value of your `<select>` tag.

Let's `select_tag` generate the following `<select>` tag in HTML:

```
<select id="quantityOptions">
  <option value="1">One item</option>
  <option value="2">Two items</option>
  <option value="3">Three items</option>
  <option value="4">Four items</option>
</select>
```

In your Javascript file, you need to look for the `.change()` event, and write the AJAX call in it.

```
$("#quantityOptions").change(function() {
    var currentQuantity = $(this).val(); // Will give you the currenlty selected option in <select> tag
    $.ajax(
        method: "POST",
         url: http://localhost:3000/update_quantity, // Or whatever custom URL you have built
        data: { val: currentQuantity },
        success: function() {
            console.log("The value finally reached on the server");
        } 
    );
});
```

Sure, you could refine this more; but you get the idea of you would do it. And don't forget to have some authentication on the server, may be you need to attach the request token with each request.

Comment: I have tried this, and it's not working. Whenever I select another option, nothing really happens, the JQuery is not getting called. Is there a gem I'm supposed to install for this to work, other than _coffee-rails_ and _jquery-rails_?

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing the correct `id` in `$('#')`? `quantityOptions` is randomly I wrote.

Comment: I am sure. I used '#quantity.' Looking online I might have to add a few things, such as remote: true to the form_for and respond_to to Controller actions. Hopefully it'll work!